# Internet Explorer multiple classes

Tags: css, internet-explorer, class

I have a link on my page which looks like:

```
<a href="www.wherever.com" class="tour-register id-tour-button"></a>
```

and my css reads:

```
.id-tour-button { display: inline-block; position:relative; z-index: 10; }
a.tour-register { background: transparent url(../img/register.png) no-repeat; width: 133px; height: 23px; }
```

This works perfectly in firefox, but in IE the link disappears, and inspection using IETester has shown that the element isn't using the second line for its styling at all.  What's wrong with what I've done?

Comment: What versions of IE have you tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple classes don't work in IE6 (it keeps the second class only, hence the behaviour you get). Which version do you exactly use?

EDIT: After Charles comment, I'm wrong about this and the problem probably comes from the display: inline-block not well understood (hence the width & height not applied because the anchor is treated like inline. Could you try with `display: block` instead? (it will probably break your design but at least you'll see what's going on)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're wrong here - IE6 doesn't work if you used nested classes in *css selectors*, not multiple classes in the HTML class attribute. So it treats .tour-register.id-tour-button the same as .id-tour-button, but it does not treat class="tour-register id-tour-button" the same as class="id-tour-button". http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/12/IE_CSS_rendering_bug_with_multiple_classnames.html

Comment: Good spot Charles! I indeed mixed my thoughts.